# If the log-likelihood is negative, should we choose it? - model comparison

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am doing linear mixed models using lme4 and this is the results of model comparison:

```
> anova(lmer5,lmer6,lmer32)

       Df   AIC   BIC logLik   Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
lmer32  9 43172 43226 -21577                              
lmer6  21 43190 43315 -21574  6.3081     12     0.8998    
lmer5  26 43162 43317 -21555 37.9971      5  3.778e-07 ***
```

As you can see, the results show that one model is significantly better than the others and normally I will choose model with smallest logLik. However in this result, the logLik is negative. Do you think it is a good idea to choose model from logLik in this case, or should I choose it from AIC or BIC instead.

As no conclusion whether AIC is better than BIC, I am confused which one I should choose. What do you think?

Comment: Why do you think the AIC and BIC don't agree? How does sample size impact AIC and BIC? Is one better than the other? Should you compare models without taking DF into account?

Comment: Are you sure you mean the *smallest* loglikelihood?

Comment: From an article, it uses the model with highest adjusted R-squared. Is it that the adjusted R-squared value is derived from the logLik^2?

Comment: The `anova` *doesn't* show what you claim. `lmer5` is significant *different* than `lmer6` in terms of the difference in model log likelihoods for the change in df. There is no comparison with `lmer32` and `lmer5` however in that output. AIC favours `lmer5`, BIC, which penalises complexity more strongly than AIC, favours `lmer32`. There is no reason to worry about the negative `logLik`; the actual value is largely irrelevant as there is a normalising constant added to it. *Differences* in likelihoods are informative however. Because `logLik` is large negative, the ICs are large positive.

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant that there is no comparison of `logLik` between `lmer32` and `lmer5` in that output. The ICs do of course allow a comparison between all models.

Comment: Thanks Gavin Simpson for your reply. Could I ask further since AIC and BIC favour different models, then which one should I use? (I am aware that their conclusion is still inconclusive)

Comment: BIC favors more parsimonious model. This effect increases with sample size. There is limited justification for choosing AIC or BIC, but generally one chooses AIC. Since generally the less parsimonious model is the more "accurate".

Comment: Right. I think I got a grip then. Thank you, Charles and everyone.

Comment: Whether log-likelihood is negative is irrelevant to any of the considerations in your question. You could (legtimately) add a million to all the log-likelihood values (making them all positive) without changing anything of consequence in a comparison of log-likelihoods.

Comment: Glen_b, so you mean the value of log-likelihood that I should be interested in is absolute log-likelihood?

Answer (score -1):

For a Cox model, logLik method returns the partial likelihood.

check  https://mailman.ucsd.edu/pipermail/ling-r-lang-l/2011-August/000282.html
you want to have **large** (i.e.  in direction of positive infinity) logLik and **small** AIC/BIC (i.e. in direction of negative infinity)

also caution BIC is only valid for comparisons of not nested models (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), if models are nested orient with AIC alone, if models are not nested you can orient for both AIC and BIC

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question.  It seem to be more like advice and maybe not all accurate.

Comment: "large (i.e. in direction of positive infinity) logLik" sounds like exactly the opposite of what should be done: it corresponds to *minimizing* the likelihood.  Could you clarify what you mean by that?